# « (Être) dans la nasse » : c'est la pêche ou la chasse et est-ce une « substance » plus ou moins ferme que le « pétrin » etc. ?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, locutions, registre-familier

Je lis qu'une loi, un dirigeant sont « dans la nasse » ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasse) ; [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nasse) ;[Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/nasse/53847?q=nasse#53492)).

> [...] *Nasse*, repris comme terme de pêche, est attesté dès 1200 au sens
> figuré de « difficulté », dans l'expression *mettre en sa nasse*, sortie
> d'usage, et remplacée par *tomber dans la nasse*, *être dans la nasse*
> (1671, *demeurer*), d'usage familier, aujourd'hui elles aussi
> archaïques. (DHLF/Rey 2011, extrait de l'article « nasse »)

Mais comment se fait-il alors que je lise ça dans un journal à grande diffusion ? Ensuite s'agit-il d'un euphémisme pour la locution adverbiale [*dans la merde*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/dans_la_merde) ; on dit (être) « dans une situation difficile *sans pouvoir la changer* »  (je souligne) : est-ce une nuance sémantique, celle de pouvoir ou non changer la donne ? Et est-ce que ça connote davantage l'univers de la *pêche* ou de la *chasse* et ressent-on la sémantique de *nasse* dans la locution ou est-ce simplement la formule « être dans » (un état) à un certain niveau ou degré ? Ou pourquoi aurait-on choisi *nasse* plutôt que *pétrin* si c'est essentiellement du même registre ?

Au TLFi je lis que [*nasse*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nasse) est employé au figuré pour la « situation fâcheuse, embarrassante; piège, traquenard » et on dit pour *être dans la nasse* « être dans l'embarras, être dans le pétrin (fam.) » mais l'exemple du premier (« Il emprunte à droite et à gauche; et quand il faudra payer à la fin, il se sauvera en Angleterre, et nous laissera dans la nasse. [...]) avec un verbe d'état (*laisser* ; ceux qu'on a laissés « sont » dans la nasse en fin de compte) ne me convainc pas d'une différence entre la locution adverbiale et la locution verbale avec *être* alors que la présentation de leur sémantique diffère légèrement (l'idée de *piège/traquenard*).

Comment: En usage courant « être dans la nasse » c'est « dans une situation difficile *sans pouvoir la changer* tout seul » tel un poisson ou crustacé piégé dans une *nasse* de pêche, que l'on soit entré dans la nasse sans s'en rendre ou qu'un tiers en ai conçu et vous ait tendu un piège à votre intention dans lequel vous vous trouvez.

Answer (score 2):

Une nasse est une terme de pêche et de chasse. Pour le pêcheur, une nasse désigne un panier oblong en osier, en treillage métallique ou en filet. Pour le chasseur, une nasse est un filet utilisé pour la capture de petits oiseaux. Dans les deux cas, il  s'agit d'un piège. Dans une nasse (à poissons), l'animal peut s'y mouvoir sans jamais en sortir. Au figuré, "Être dans la nasse" signifie donc bien à se sentir piégé, être « dans une situation difficile sans pouvoir la changer tout seul ».

La nuance avec "être dans le pétrin" se trouve vraisemblablement dans cette notion de mobilité. Si l'on est tombé dans un pétrin (rempli de pâte à pain), il est difficile de se mouvoir, mais il est possible de s'en sortir. Si l'on est entré dans une nasse, il est possible de s'y mouvoir, mais impossible de s'enfuir.

Comment: Aussi la notion de nasse sous-entend un piège tendu par quelqu'un, alors qu'être dans le pétrin est plutôt lié à certains aléas qu'à une volonté direct de quelqu'un.